# Develop a Layout like Windows Tile

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout

As I want to develop a layout as show below image .I have implemented layout file but I want to place the image and text in the center of the button .Please any one can suggest me...

the which i have implemented is

windows_8.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.26"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" 
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.84"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="118dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.00" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="156dp"
            android:layout_height="122dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Consider using a GridLayout. Tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_the_Android_GridLayout_in_XML_Layout_Resources

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Quilt View Library  https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary or can simply use Gridview in android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Enjoy !